# How long will Manifest v2 be supported in developer mode?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

Here they say that in June 2023 Manifest v2 extension will no longer run in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/

Does it also mean that it won't be possible to load manifest v2 extensions in developer mode? Are there any official links or statements about this?

Comment: Most likely so, judging by the fact Google pretends MV3 is usable and enforces it as the only option in the web store this month even though it's only partly implemented and its implementation has severe bugs that aren't getting any developer attention for months. Anyway, you should ask for an official clarification in the [extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions), not here.

Comment: Thanks, I've found this answer "Yes, locally running manifest versions is dependent on the Chrome browser being able to run it - when this ceases in January 2023 this will also end." here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/H12F2kETGpg/m/mCmAaabTAwAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this comment in the Chrome Extensions Google Group: "Yes, locally running manifest versions is dependent on the Chrome browser being able to run it - when this ceases in January 2023 this will also end."
Here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/H12F2kETGpg/m/mCmAaabTAwAJ

So apparently manifest v2 extensions will no longer be supported in developer mode from January 2023.